# Running Fleck (or any) Websocket server on Windows Azure

Tags: c#, azure, websocket

I would like to run a WebSocket server off a worker role in Azure.

This works fine locally on the emulator, but there is a windows firewall prompt the first time the socket server runs.

I'm wondering if anyone would know how to overcome the connection issues with regards to sockets on Azure.

My socket server implementation: `OnStart`

```
var server = new WebSocketServer("ws://theappname.cloudapp.net:8080/");

server.Start(socket =>
{
    socket.OnOpen = () =>
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Connected to " + socket.ConnectionInfo.ClientIpAddress,"Information");
         _sockets.Add(socket);
    };
});
.... etc
```

The client implementation:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://theappname.cloudapp.net:8080");

socket.onopen = function () {
    status.html("Connection Opened");
};
socket.onclose = function () {
    status.html("Connection Closed");
}
```

---

The status changes to `closed` a few seconds after loading the page.

---

My endpoint for the worker role below:

`WebSocket  Input   http    8080        <Not Set>`

---

I have now tried to bind to the internal IP address using the following:

`RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["WebSocket"].IPEndpoint.ToString();`

---

**SOLUTION**

For the sake of anyone else facing this when implementing websockets on Azure;

1. Your firewall probably will deny your connection if not on port 80 or 8080 so create a separate deployment for it.
2. Endpoint must be set to TCP and not HTTP for the correct firewall rules to be created. (see image)

[image: Endpoint Configuration]

Comment: Just for the sake of trial, why don't you change your Input Endpoit from "http" to "tcp" protocol. And explicitly set the local port to 8080 (which in your case is <Not Set>). Also you have to keep in mind that Windows Azure Load Balancer would kill any connection that is idleing for more than 60 seconds.

Comment: @astaykov - Your comment led to the solution, please post below so I can +cred you. Thanks.

Comment: @astaykov Do you have your full implementation? I am trying to get mine to work and have never done this before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for the sake of trial, why don't you change your Input Endpoit from "http" to "tcp" protocol. And explicitly set the local port to 8080 (which in your case is ). Also you have to keep in mind that Windows Azure Load Balancer would kill any connection that is idleing for more than 60 seconds, so you might want to implement some kind of "ping" solution to keep the connection open.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments about keeping the connection open, was considering something similar.

Comment: Isn't the connection keeping open sending PING by protocol itself?

Comment: protocol by itself will not send anything. Protocol is just definition on paper. It is protocol implementation that have to take care of these things. So if you do open socket and do not send anything, the connection will be terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this introductory video that Steve Marx (@smarx) put together on [how to run node.js on Windows Azure](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Windows-Azure-Developer-Experience-Videos/Nodejs-Windows-Azure-Introduction).

Comment: Thanks, I have worked extensively with node.js and socket.io; unfortunately this is not the context i'm presented with.