# Running Fleck server in ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, websocket, server

I'm trying to host a `websocket` server inside an ASP.NET application like this:

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var server = new WebSocketServer("ws://127.0.0.1:8080");
    Server.Start(socket => socket.OnOpen = () => OnUserConnect(socket));
}

private void OnUserConnect(IWebSocketConnection socket)
{
    // Some application logic.
}
```

When I test my application on my computer all is fine and I'm able to connect to this server. But when I deploy this application to Azure I'm **getting timeout error**. So, I suppose that I just need to provide appropriate port that is opened in Azure Web App? And If the answer is yes then what port is appropriate?

**Edit**

I tried to change port to 80 and I've got this error:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

So I guess, this port is not right either, or maybe I must add something to config (though, I've enabled WebSockets in my Web App settings).

Comment: Did you try to enable WebSockets in the Settings pane on the WebApp dashboard?

Comment: Yep (I wrote it in question already)

Comment: Ok. Can you try to re-create the WebApp, enabling the WS immediately after that, and deploy the app? That issue should be directed to the technical support, but let's try from that simple workaround.

Comment: Just found -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177089/running-fleck-or-any-websocket-server-on-windows-azure?rq=1 . Did you see that?

Comment: Yes, I've seen this question, but this method is only applicable to Cloud Service and not to Web App. If only Web App could have ServiceDefinition.csdef...

Comment: I've tried to re-create Web App but it doesn't seem to help.